# How to convert mouse movement to android movement in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Hey guys im new to game development on android, and i have this dilema. The problem is that i dont know how to convert my "void OnMouseDown" to android syntax.  Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float relaseTime = .15f;
    private bool isPressed = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (isPressed)
        {
            rb.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        isPressed = true;
        rb.isKinematic = true;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        isPressed = false;
        rb.isKinematic = false;

        StartCoroutine(Realase());
    }

    IEnumerator Realase()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(relaseTime);
        GetComponent<SpringJoint2D>().enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Input.GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)

Instead of the events `OnWhatever` for the mouse you check for the [touchPhase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html) in the `Update`.

Like so:

```
public class TouchPhaseExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 startPos;
    public Vector2 direction;

    public Text m_Text;
    string message;

    void Update()
    {
        //Update the Text on the screen depending on current TouchPhase, and the current direction vector
        m_Text.text = "Touch : " + message + "in direction" + direction;

        // Track a single touch as a direction control.
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            // Handle finger movements based on TouchPhase
            switch (touch.phase)
            {
                //When a touch has first been detected, change the message and record the starting position
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    // Record initial touch position.
                    startPos = touch.position;
                    message = "Begun ";
                    break;

                //Determine if the touch is a moving touch
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    // Determine direction by comparing the current touch position with the initial one
                    direction = touch.position - startPos;
                    message = "Moving ";
                    break;

                case TouchPhase.Ended:
                    // Report that the touch has ended when it ends
                    message = "Ending ";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```